# How to get content inside tag with beautifulsoup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to get the number of comments that a video has received on youtube with `requests` and `beautifulSoup`. When I checked the elements tab under developer options in chrome this is what I found
[image]

To target the `yt-formatted-string` tag I did the following

```
response = requests.get(url)
soup = bs(response.text, "html.parser")

print(soup.find("yt-formatted-string", {"class": "count-text"}).text)
```

But this gives me the following error

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

I guess this happens as the tag was not found. So I tried printing all the tags using `soup.find_all()` as follows

```
print([tag.name for tag in soup.find_all()])
```

This gives the following result

```
['html', 'head', 'meta', 'script', 'script', 'script', 'link', 'link', 'link', 'link', 'link', 'script', 'script', 'script', 'script', 'script', 'script', 'script', 'script', 'script', 'script', 'script', 'script', 'link', 'script', 'link', 'link', 'link', 'link', 'style', 'style', 'style', 'style', 'style', 'meta', 'link', 'link', 'script', 'script', 'link', 'link', 'link', 'title', 'meta', 'meta', 'meta', 'link', 'link', 'link', 'link', 'link', 'link', 'meta', 'meta', 'meta', 'meta', 'meta', 'meta', 'meta', 'meta', 'meta', 'meta', 'meta', 'meta', 'meta', 'meta', 'meta', 'meta', 'meta', 'meta', 'meta', 'meta', 'meta', 'meta', 'meta', 'meta', 'meta', 'meta', 'meta', 'meta', 'meta', 'meta', 'meta', 'meta', 'meta', 'meta', 'meta', 'meta', 'meta', 'meta', 'meta', 'meta', 'meta', 'meta', 'meta', 'meta', 'meta', 'meta', 'meta', 'meta', 'meta', 'meta', 'meta', 'meta', 'meta', 'meta', 'meta', 'meta', 'meta', 'meta', 'meta', 'meta', 'meta', 'meta', 'meta', 'div', 'link', 'meta', 'meta', 'meta', 'meta', 'meta', 'meta', 'meta', 'span', 'link', 'link', 'script', 'link', 'span', 'link', 'meta', 'meta', 'link', 'meta', 'meta', 'meta', 'meta', 'meta', 'meta', 'meta', 'meta', 'meta', 'body', 'script', 'div', 'div', 'div', 'script', 'script', 'script', 'script', 'script', 'script', 'script', 'script', 'iframe', 'ytd-app', 'ytd-masthead', 'div', 'div', 'input', 'svg', 'g', 'path', 'div', 'a', 'svg', 'g', 'g', 'path', 'path', 'g', 'g', 'path', 'path', 'path', 'path', 'path', 'path', 'path', 'a', 'svg', 'g', 'g', 'path', 'path', 'g', 'path', 'path', 'path', 'path', 'path', 'path', 'path', 'path', 'span', 'div', 'div', 'div', 'div', 'div', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'div', 'div', 'script', 'script', 'script', 'script', 'script', 'script', 'script', 'script', 'script', 'script', 'div', 'div', 'div', 'div', 'div', 'div', 'div', 'div', 'div', 'div', 'div', 'div', 'div', 'div', 'div', 'div', 'div', 'div', 'div', 'div', 'div', 'div', 'div', 'div', 'div', 'div', 'div', 'div', 'div', 'div', 'div', 'div', 'div', 'div', 'div', 'div', 'div', 'div', 'div', 'div', 'div', 'div', 'div', 'div', 'div', 'div', 'div', 'div', 'div', 'div', 'div', 'div', 'div', 'div', 'div', 'div', 'div', 'div', 'div', 'div', 'div', 'div', 'div', 'div', 'div', 'div', 'div', 'div', 'div', 'div', 'div', 'div', 'div', 'div', 'div', 'div', 'div', 'div', 'div', 'div', 'div', 'div', 'div', 'div', 'div', 'script', 'script', 'script', 'script', 'script', 'script', 'script', 'script']
```

I notice that the tag `yt-formatted-string` does not exist in the list.

How do I get the comments count using beautifulsoup?

PS: I can achieve this using Selenium, but there are other requirements which make selenium not so desirable here.

Comment: Uhm, mind sharing the URL?

Comment: @baduker I suspect this is the same for each youtube video, so you can just get a random one to test.

Comment: What about using pytube package? Isn't it easier and direct?

Answer (score 1):

If you inspect the HTML you'll see the following line in the `<head>`:

```html
<meta itemprop="interactionCount" content="75068">
```

This indicates the viewcount and is much more easy to find using BeautifulSoup

---

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

pages = requests.get('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HssXq2OsumY')
soup = BeautifulSoup(pages.content, 'html.parser')

interactionCount = soup.find('meta', attrs={'itemprop':'interactionCount'})['content']

print(interactionCount)
```

Will show `75077` for [this youtube vid](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HssXq2OsumY)

[image]

Comment: This is the view count. I was specifically asking about the comment count which is not available in the meta tags. This seems to be populated using JS and is not available in the page content initially. I guess I have to use selenium or the youtube API to get this data

Comment: @Sashaank the quantity of comments (*and the comments*) are loaded in a second request that the page makes, so, you cannot get this value with BeautifulSoup...probably with Selenium or use YouTube Data API